# Shared Embedded Resource Not Working

Tags: vb.net, embedded-resource

I have a Winforms app and several class library projects in one solution. One of those libs is referenced by the app and all of the other libs, as it has common functions and a module they all share.  The App does not use Application Framework and cannot because it has a Sub Main entry point so that it can be run as a windows service.  All references from the app to the libs and from the libs to the common one have Copy Local = False, and they're all linked as embedded resources to the app.

In Sub Main, I have:

```
AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf AssemblyResolve
```

and AssemblyResolve is a function in a module of the app and that works for all the libs except that common one.  If I mark the common lib to Copy Local = True in the app, everything works.  If the common one is not copied, the app crashes with a file not found error and never reaches the AddHandler line in Sub Main.

I do not want to distribute that DLL with the app separately...the app is run through a licensing package and code signed.

**What can I do to make this common lib work properly embedded?**

Comment: Show the assemblyresolve function as well as your error. It should return an assembly that is loaded...

Comment: As stated, it's not reaching the AddHandler in the first place.

Comment: Have you used dependency walker to see what is missing?

Comment: I'll try that...the crash is because of a file not found because the DLL isn't copied and it hasn't wired up the AssemblyResolve yet.

Comment: In the app's Main module there are declarations of objects that are defined in the other libs, which I'm sure reference the common one.  I just can't get the handler wired up early enough.